# Transforming an original image to fill a fixed Table size twice as big in CSS animation

Tags: css, animation, transform

This is what I have so far and the animation is working, but is going to the bottom right direction and not filling my end table 1181px 555px the original image starting size is 567px 378px. And I looking for the animation to slowly increase to fill the final (table size) destination.

```
<style type="text/css">

body{
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    table: 1181px 555px;
    

}

#img{
  
  transform-origin: left top;
  animation: scale 6s normal forwards;
  padding-top: 250px;
  padding-left: 340px;
 
    
}

@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
   }
    25% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
   }
    50% {
    transform: scale(2.0);
   }
    75% {
    transform: scale(2.5);
   }
    100% {
    transform: scale(3.0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with some more additional code. Perhaps create a snippet so we can see the problem in full action.

Comment: This is all that you are missing,</head>

/><body>

<div align="center"><img src="Wine Barrels.jpg" width="567" height="378"  align="absmiddle" id="img" />
</body>
</html>